# errors when going from codeblocks to visual studio (glfw/glew)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks, glew, glfw

I have a project in glfw that I was creating in codeblocks, as I have always wanted to try out visual studio i have decided to transfer it, the code compiles fine when run in codeblocks. However in visual studio I get the following errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl Main_Loop(void)" (?Main_Loop@@YAXXZ)    c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl Init(void)" (?Init@@YAXXZ)    c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glFrustum@48 referenced in function "void __cdecl Init(void)" (?Init@@YAXXZ)   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl Draw(class TextRenderer,class Button)" (?Draw@@YAXVTextRenderer@@VButton@@@Z)    c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glMatrixMode@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl Init(void)" (?Init@@YAXXZ) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glTranslatef@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl Draw(class TextRenderer,class Button)" (?Draw@@YAXVTextRenderer@@VButton@@@Z) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function "void __cdecl glInit(void)" (?glInit@@YAXXZ) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewIsSupported@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl glInit(void)" (?glInit@@YAXXZ)  c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function "void __cdecl Init(void)" (?Init@@YAXXZ) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwTerminate referenced in function "void __cdecl Shut_Down(int)" (?Shut_Down@@YAXH@Z)  c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwOpenWindow referenced in function "void __cdecl Init(void)" (?Init@@YAXXZ)   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwSetWindowTitle referenced in function "void __cdecl Init(void)" (?Init@@YAXXZ)   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   14  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwSwapBuffers referenced in function "void __cdecl Main_Loop(void)" (?Main_Loop@@YAXXZ)    c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   15  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwGetWindowParam referenced in function "void __cdecl Main_Loop(void)" (?Main_Loop@@YAXXZ) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__FT_Init_FreeType referenced in function "void __cdecl fontInit(void)" (?fontInit@@YAXXZ)   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__FT_New_Face referenced in function "void __cdecl fontInit(void)" (?fontInit@@YAXXZ)    c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\main.obj    Project1
Error   18  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBegin@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Button::render(void)" (?render@Button@@UAEXXZ)   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\Button.obj  Project1
Error   19  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBegin@4  c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   20  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnd@0 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Button::render(void)" (?render@Button@@UAEXXZ) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\Button.obj  Project1
Error   21  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnd@0    c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   22  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glVertex2f@8 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Button::render(void)" (?render@Button@@UAEXXZ)    c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\Button.obj  Project1
Error   23  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glVertex2f@8   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   24  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor3f@12 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall Button::render(void)" (?render@Button@@UAEXXZ)    c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\Button.obj  Project1
Error   25  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__glColor3f@12   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   26  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBindTexture@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   27  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glBlendFunc@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z)   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   28  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDeleteTextures@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z)  c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   29  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDisable@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   30  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glEnable@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z)  c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   31  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGenTextures@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   32  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glPixelStorei@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   33  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glScalef@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   34  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glTexCoord2f@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z)  c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   35  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glTexImage2D@36 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   36  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glTexParameteri@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TextRenderer::draw(struct FT_Bitmap_ *,float,float)" (?draw@TextRenderer@@QAEXPAUFT_Bitmap_@@MM@Z)  c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   37  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__FT_Set_Char_Size referenced in function "public: __thiscall TextRenderer::TextRenderer(float,float,struct FT_FaceRec_ * *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float)" (??0TextRenderer@@QAE@MMPAPAUFT_FaceRec_@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@Z) c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   38  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__FT_Load_Glyph referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall TextRenderer::render(void)" (?render@TextRenderer@@UAEXXZ)   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   39  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__FT_Get_Char_Index referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall TextRenderer::render(void)" (?render@TextRenderer@@UAEXXZ)   c:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\TextRenderer.obj    Project1
Error   40  error LNK1120: 34 unresolved externals  c:\users\samuel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe   Project1
```

what is this error caused by?

Edit: based on your responses it appears that I was linking libraries incorrectly, now I get none of the above errors but I get a new one: 
[image: Error]
More info:

This is the output visual studio is giving me

> 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program
>   Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\glew32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System\freetype6.dll'.
>   Module was built without symbols. 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'Project1.exe'
>   (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot
>   find or open the PDB file. 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System\zlib1.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. First-chance exception at 0x77BEB0AE
>   (ntdll.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found. The
>   program '[9044] Project1.exe' has exited with code -1073741511
>   (0xc0000139) 'Entry Point Not Found'.

Comment: you need to link libraries, glfw, glew, opengl32, because you are including only headers and compiler needs binaries too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: I thought I had - I went to the include directories and added the include and lib foldersas it would not allow me to select the individual files-like codeblocks does

Comment: it allows everything the same as codeblocks, only need to know how to use it

Comment: can you explain how then?

Comment: http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/settings_vc10.html
should help you, otherwise search in google "visual studio c++ linker/linking tutorial"

Comment: That new error does not make any kind of sense. At least because Project.exe is (hopefully) not a dynamic link library.

Comment: Try if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/795433/2700399) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17157514/2700399) answer helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments to the question, I think I can provide a decent answer. You need to link some libraries (glfw, glew, opengl23). In Visual Studio, adding libraries is done in the `Linker` section of your project's properties. More specifically: `Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies`.

Additional search directories for the libraries can be added at `Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories`.